# How do i remove #N/A in a IF formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is the formula:

> `=IF(I11=H11,$H$10,IF(I11=G11,$G$10,IF(I11=F11,$F$10,IF(I11=E11,$E$10,IF(I11=D11,$D$10,IF(I11=C11,$C$10,IF(I11=B11,$B$10)))))))`

Comment: Please post some data too,  without that it's not possible to help you with the best solution.  Your formula do the same that `INDEX($B$10:$H$10,MATCH(I11,B11:H11,0))` would do.  Why do you need this long one? ?

Comment: Can you provide some context on the #N/A?  Where are you seeing it?  What are the referenced cell values that produce it?  What condition are you trying to catch (is it unexpected, or possible and you want to avoid a resulting error condition, or you want to look for it and do something if you see it)?

Answer (score 1):

The `#NA` has potentially nothing to do with the formula, but with the cells you are referencing. If one of those cells has an error, using it in a formula would propagate the problem on.

It could be because your last `IF` has no else:
`...,IF(I11=B11,$B$10)))))))` - add something for what should happen there:
`...,IF(I11=B11,$B$10,"")))))))` - my example shows "" = *nothing* for that case, but you can use whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use "iferror" if it could be a valid situation for source data to have differing formats that might cause the #NA outcome.